# Terminal window fills the screen in OS X Lion

Tags: macos, osx-lion, terminal.app

When I open Terminal, it fills the screen, there is no way to minimize it. There is no toolbar at the top. It is just a screen of white, with the bash prompt.

I am used to Linux, and controlling a terminal window is normally a simple thing for me. When it is time to end I end up having to do a `Cmd + Q` to exit. I do not have any other app/utility in Mac do this.

How do I get a Terminal window to open up in a 'normal window', i.e. with a border, sizeable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That probably means you're in full screen mode. If you move the mouse to the top the menubar should slide down. There you have a button on the right with two diagonal arrows.

Pressing that button should resize your terminal windows (well, that's true for all full-screen apps)

Comment: No reason to feel dumb. That's one of the hurdles you have with a new OS. And to be honest I had to search for a minute or two, too the first time I entered a full-screen mode. First I hit the `ESC` about a zillion times :) and then well, moved the mouse the the edges to see if something pops up.